# Selecionar dias dentro de data para montagem de turno de trabalho

Tags: mysql, data

Estou precisando de uma função que insira datas selecionadas no `Datapicker`

```
var date = new Date();
$('#pre-select-dates').multiDatesPicker({
    addDates: [date.setDate(14), date.setDate(19)]
});
```

Comment: Precisamos de mais informação. Tem alguma preferencia de linguagem ou já tem alguma infra em mente?

Comment: seria com php mysql, teria um cadastro de Turno e em turno eu selecionaria os dias a ser trabalhado, e quantas horas ele deveria trabalhar no turno.

Comment: Você já montou suas tabelas?

Comment: não, estou pensando em como montar, colamos um calendário aberto, o usuario somente irá clica e selecionar os dias e cada dia terá jornada de horas trabalhadas.

Comment: Não estou a perceber o que você quer fazer poderá explicar melhor?

Comment: Claro explico sim, irei cadastrar um funcionário  quando eu cadastro o funcionário tenho que adicionar o turno de trabalho e quantas horas ele irá trabalhar no dia.

Comment: exemplo abre calendário a cada vez que ele marcar um dia, irá fazer um insert no banco desse dia, quando desselecionar o dia ele faz o delete no banco .

Comment: encontrei data_piker calendário jquery só preciso que ele selecione mais de uma data para fazer os inputs  e mantenha o calendário colorido para as datas selecionadas, e inputalas todas no banco